# Spring framework for SAML - WebSSOProfileImpl

Tags: java, spring, saml-2.0

In the code below, can anyone tell me how the assertion consumer service is being derived, if I am not setting this value in my metadata.

What is happening now is that a user is entering a URL on the command line like:

http://test1:11100/blah/blah/login.jsp

The application redirects OK.  But the saml request being generated has a completely different ACS, i.e...
 AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://test5:11101/blah/saml/SSO

This causes issues because the response has the wrong URL (should have the test1 one above).

It is not clear to me how the ip and port are derived, if I am not supplying this information in my code or configuration.

I basically want the request to have the IP/port that the user enters.

Thanks.

### from: org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl.java

protected AssertionConsumerService getAssertionConsumerService(WebSSOProfileOptions options, IDPSSODescriptor idpSSODescriptor, SPSSODescriptor spDescriptor) throws MetadataProviderException {

```
    List<AssertionConsumerService> services = spDescriptor.getAssertionConsumerServices();

    // Use user preference
    if (options.getAssertionConsumerIndex() != null) {
        for (AssertionConsumerService service : services) {
            if (options.getAssertionConsumerIndex().equals(service.getIndex())) {
                if (!isEndpointSupported(service)) {
                    throw new MetadataProviderException("Endpoint designated by the value in the WebSSOProfileOptions is not supported by this profile");
                } else {
                    log.debug("Using consumer service determined by user preference with binding {}", service.getBinding());
                    return service;
                }
            }
        }
        throw new MetadataProviderException("AssertionConsumerIndex " + options.getAssertionConsumerIndex() + " not found for spDescriptor " + spDescriptor);
    }

    // Use default
    if (spDescriptor.getDefaultAssertionConsumerService() != null && isEndpointSupported(spDescriptor.getDefaultAssertionConsumerService())) {
        AssertionConsumerService service = spDescriptor.getDefaultAssertionConsumerService();
        log.debug("Using default consumer service with binding {}", service.getBinding());
        return service;
    }

    // Iterate and find first match
    if (services.size() > 0) {
        for (AssertionConsumerService service : services) {
            if (isEndpointSupported(service)) {
                log.debug("Using first available consumer service with binding {}", service.getBinding());
                return service;
            }
        }
    }

    throw new MetadataProviderException("Service provider has no assertion consumer service available for the selected profile " + spDescriptor);

}
```